# Listener for activate application in Java Swing

Tags: java, swing, event-listener

I need to run few task when switching to my Java Swing application from other application. Let say, I have opened my application (TestApp) first and opened Notepad. Now both applications are opened and Notepad is focused. When I minimize Notepad or click on the TestApp icon in the taskbar or select the TestApp using Alt + Tab, TestApp will become current application and gets focused. In this moment, I need to run some task. Is there any listener in Java Swing / JavaFx to listen to this application switch event?

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: Swing or javafx?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes there is a listener exactly for that case.
[WindowListener](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/WindowListener.html) provides the method [windowActivated(WindowEvent)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/WindowListener.html#windowActivated(java.awt.event.WindowEvent)) which gets called every time the window gets activated (gets focused).

Simply implement this interface and implement the method to use it.

Answer (score 3):

You are looking for WindowFocusListener:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/event/WindowFocusListener.html